# Gesture filtering on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, filter, uiscrollview, gestures

How can I block certain gestures from being sent to a UIScrollView? E.g. when the scrollview receives a gesture, have sent that gesture to my code. If my code finds it of relevance, let the code respond to it. Otherwise, I'd like the code to allow the scrollview to respond to it normally.

I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Any gestures inside the scrollview should be sent. Scrolling gestures are the ones I want to filter, and possible send forwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for gesture recognizers. Apple has a pretty good [implementation guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW13).

Comment: Thanks a ton :) After reading a bit, it looks like the article you sent has EVERYTHING I need. I can just detach existing recognizers from the scrollview, and re implement them with my own recognition function and go from there :)  I'm going to hold off form officially marking this as the answer until I get code working though.